# WPF Ninject with Datacontext and constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-injection, ninject

Good day all,
            I have some experience with WPF but I am still at the beginning with MVVM and now I would like to use DI with ninject. When I worked with forms I used ninject normally by making a kernel with the bindings to load and inserting the parameters in the constructor, i see this is not possible now that i have to use DataContext.
I have a main window with buttons and a contructor in View Models, in order to use the buttons in the window I that I need to pass the parameters from the binding in the constructor, but if I do so I get an error because the datacontext wants a parameterless constructor, I believe there is an obvious solution I could not find a specific one on the Ninject (sites) and online the only workarounds use some complicate factory pattern which seems to overkill, does anyone know how to solve the problem?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="StretchApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StretchApp"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:StretchApp.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" Background="LightGray"
    DataContextChanged="MainWindow_DataContextChanged">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace StretchApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IHavePassword
    {
        private IKernel container;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(MainWindow_DataContextChanged);
        }
        void MainWindow_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dc = DataContext as IClosableViewModel;
            dc.CloseWindowEvent += new EventHandler(dc_CloseWindowEvent);
        }
        void dc_CloseWindowEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="StretchApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StretchApp"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:StretchApp.ViewModels">

    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.xs

```
sing Ninject;
using StretchApp.Helper;
using StretchApp.Helper.Interfaces;
using System.Windows;

namespace StretchApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private IKernel container;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var container = new StandardKernel();

            // Register types
            container.Bind<IEncrypterHelper>().To<EncrypterHelper>();
            container.Bind<Window>().To<MainWindow>();

            // Show the main window.
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Show();

        }
        private void ComposeObjects()
        {
            Current.MainWindow = this.container.Get<MainWindow>();
        }

        private void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            this.container = new StandardKernel();
            container.Bind<IEncrypterHelper>().To<EncrypterHelper>();

        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
        public MainViewModel(IEncrypterHelper encrypterHelper)
        {
           _encrypterHelper = encrypterHelper;

        }
```

Comment: You are free to use constructors with parameters, if you are not doing so in XAML. Anyway, I think you should use some MVVM framework, because most of them already have a solutions for what you asking. Take a look at [Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't instantiate the view model in your XAML markup like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

You would only do this in very simple scenarios and it's not possible to use this approach if you want to inject the `MainViewModel` with some dependencies. Instead you could set the `DataContext` property of the view programmatically, for example in your `OnStartup` method where you instantiate the `MainWindow`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var container = new StandardKernel();

    // Register types
    container.Bind<IEncrypterHelper>().To<EncrypterHelper>();
    container.Bind<Window>().To<MainWindow>();

    // Show the main window.
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    mw.DataContext = container.Get<MainWindowViewModel>();
    mw.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, with some modifications on the bindings it works. Thank you